# Convert a 3d-array into 2d-array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a 3d-array of shape (m, n, l) into 2d-array of shape (m*n, l) as follows:

```
A = [[[1, 2],[3, 4]],  [[5, 6],[7, 8]]]
```

to

```
B = [[1, 3, 2, 4], [5, 7, 6, 8]]
```

For each i in range(l), I used

```
reshape(A[i, :, :], (1, -1), order='F')
```

It works. However when I use `signal.hilbert(B)`, I obtain the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:/IMFsPasesAndDifferences_FV/FollowingTheSameLogicAsMatlab.py", line 41, in <module>
    HilbertMatrix = signal.hilbert(TempMatrix)   File "C:\Users\Tiwa\Anaconda3\envs\IMFsPasesAndDifferences_FV\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 1624, in hilbert
    Xf = fftpack.fft(x, N, axis=axis)   File "C:\Users\Tiwa\Anaconda3\envs\IMFsPasesAndDifferences_FV\lib\site-packages\scipy\fftpack\basic.py", line 284, in fft
    return work_function(tmp,n,1,0,overwrite_x)
_fftpack.error: failed in converting 1st argument `x' of _fftpack.zrfft to C/Fortran array
```

I am wondering if it exists another way to reshape the matrix without using **order='F'**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have desktop atm, but would swapping the first two axes before reshaping work?

Comment: Are you looking for `numpy.reshape(A, (2, -1))`?

Comment: Can you show how you build `B`? Your code won't produce the array you're asking for the way you have it now.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Could you please explain why should we avoid `reshape` in this case?

Comment: @MykolaZotko. Why should we avoid reshaping? I don't remember ever saying that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You commented on the answer `numpy.reshape(A, (2, -1))`

Comment: @MykolaZotko. Oh. Nothing wrong with the reshape if you prep the array first. Just doing the reshape will not order the elements correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The reshape you are showing is from `(l, m, n)` to `(l, m * n)`, not `(l * m, n)`. You can simulate F order while keeping C order by swapping the last two axes:

```
B = np.swapaxes(A, -2, -1).reshape(A.shape[0], -1)
```

Note that this will copy your data, since the array will not be contiguous after the swap.

Answer (score 0):

does this answer your Question?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[[1, 2],[3, 4]],  [[5, 6],[7, 8]]])

B = A.T.reshape(-1, A.shape[2]).T
```